# What is the "preamble" to a ballot measure called?

Tags: united-states, legal-terms, oregon, elections

Oregon ballot measures have this basic format (this particular one is an initiative for a constitutional amendment, but referendums [referenda?] are similar, as are measures for regular legislation):

> Whereas, ABC is good and XYZ is bad, and
>
> Whereas, the state government currently promotes XYZ rather than ABC, and
>
> Whereas, the state government should promote good things,
>
> Be it enacted by the people of the State of Oregon,
>
> Article 1, Section 1 of the Oregon Constitution is amended to read,
>
> > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

What is the "whereas" part called?

Comment: I would call it a preamble lol, this is also listed in the legal definitions linked in the accepted answer.

Comment: Could you Post some example more obvious or more useful, if not both?

Most obviously, I mean could you Post an example stopping at "ABC is good and XYZ is bad…" and leaving out the rest? Otherwise, is it not clear that your idea is based on, and worth as much as "Lorem ipsum… etc"?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin only the general format matters; I was just asking what the "whereas" part is called. It doesn't need to be a real[istic] measure.

Comment: Were asking what the "preamble" to a ballot measure is called,  or not?

In 'What is the "preamble" to a ballot measure called?' what room is there for a "whereas" part?

Where is there any room for any measure, real(istic) or not?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I was asking "what is the 'preamble' part called," and including a fake ballot measure to demonstrate what I was talking about.

Comment: Thanks and because of that clarification, please be more sure than you'd thought before, this is about not "law" but "English" even though this use of English applies almost solely to law.

The "Whereas part" has no name in either English or law. "Whereas" is just a word, like "ABC" or "good" or "XYZ" or "bad".

There is no specific nor useful name for that in either law or English.

If it came into this, the 'preamble' part would be called 'the preamble' but it doesn't.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are called *recitals*.

See:

- Termly legal dictionary: [recital](https://termly.io/legal-dictionary/recital/)
- US Legal: [recital](https://definitions.uslegal.com/r/recitals/)
- Wikipedia: [recital (law)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recital_(law))
- Wiktionary: [recital, n. 5 (law)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recital#Noun)

Comment: I suspect you're giving more than is needed. 'Someone' clarified the OQ with "only the general format matters; I was just asking what the "whereas" part is called. It doesn't need to be a real[istic] measure" which seems to side-line your otherwise excellent Answer!

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin this answer is exactly what I was looking for.